# Snakemake + Docker Volumes - "Missing Rule Exception"

Tags: docker, snakemake

I'm trying to use snakemake with a docker image, but am having trouble with the docker volume.  Unfortunately, there are no details on how to use 'singularity-args' to do this.

My snakemake file is:

```
rule all:
    input:
        'a/file3.txt'

rule step1:
    output:
        touch('a/file1.txt')

rule step2:
    input:
        rules.step1.output[0]
    output:
        'a/file2.txt'
    params:
        text = 'this is a test',
        path = '/data/file2.txt'
    singularity:
        "docker://XXX/test"
    shell:
        "python test.py {params.text} {params.path}"

rule step3:
    input:
        rules.step2.output[0]
    output:
        touch('a/file3.txt')
```

The docker image is basically a python file that writes a string to file (for testing purposes).  I'm trying to mount my home directory to the docker /data directory.  With docker, I'm able to mount a volume using '-v'.

What is the correct way of doing this with snakemake?

I've tried the following commands (on MacOS and Ubuntu 18.04) and both have failed.

```
snakemake -s pipeline.py --use-singularity --singularity-args “-B /home/XXX/snakemake/a:/data”
snakemake -s pipeline.py --use-singularity --singularity-args “-B /home/XXX/snakemake/a”
```

The error message is:

```
No rule to produce /home/XXX/snakemake/a:/data” (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
```

Am I missing a step?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just a trivial check... In your command lines you have tilted double quotes (`“`) instead of the straight ones (`"`), e.g.:

```
snakemake -s pipeline.py --use-singularity --singularity-args “-B /home/XXX/snakemake/a”
```

Maybe you are are copying and pasting from a text editor that uses the tilted quotes? I would use straight quotes as the other type would probably be interpreted in the wrong way.

Comment: that was it!  I always use TextEdit for notes, and it must have replaced the quotes.  Great catch!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working on Ubuntu 18.04 with the following command:

```
SINGULARITY_BINDPATH=“/home/XXX/snakemake/a:/data”; snakemake -s pipeline.py --latency-wait 10 --use-singularity
```

Unfortunately I wasn’t able to get the flag “--singularity-args” to work. Regardless of using ‘--bind’ or ‘-B’, I got the error “No rule to produce /Users/XXX/Devel/snakemake/a:/data”.

I’m using Snakemake 5.6.0 inside a Python3 virtual environment.
Also, on a side note, I don’t believe the MacOS singularity binary works. It had issues with Snakemake.

This work-around is good enough for now.

**UPDATE**

While this solution worked, the real solution (typo) was provided by @dariober.